# how can i get this metamask thingy when user is logged in?

Tags: metamask

Im talking about how i can implement this metamask navbar icon?

[image]

I would like to make it look like this when people are logged in with metamask
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could have a function such as the following:

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
const FALLBACK_WEB3_PROVIDER = process.env.REACT_APP_NETWORK || 'http://0.0.0.0:8545';

const getWeb3 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
    window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
      // Modern dapp browsers...
      if (window.ethereum) {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        try {
          // Request account access if needed
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          // Acccounts now exposed
          resolve(web3);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      }
      // Legacy dapp browsers...
      else if (window.web3) {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = window.web3;
        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
      // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
      else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          FALLBACK_WEB3_PROVIDER
        );
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log("No web3 instance injected, using Infura/Local web3.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then you could do this:

```js
async function getEthereumAccounts() {
    const web3 = await getWeb3();
    // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    return acccounts || [];
}
```

At this point, `accounts` should be an array of available addresses, and accounts[0] should be the current address, from that point onwards you can use the address and put it into your user interface.

Comment: ok, and how do i get the icon im talking about?

Comment: I think this is the React component they are using: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/develop/ui/app/components/ui/identicon/identicon.component.js

Comment: ok but this is python code right?
is there anything for javascript

Comment: This is Javascript. Using React.js: https://reactjs.org/

Comment: There are instructions here to run MetaMask locally in case you want to see how a React user-interface works and fits in with the rest of the application: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension

Comment: Javascript has changed a lot (for the better) over the last ~ 5 years, in case the syntax looks different to the Javascript you may be accustomed to. 